# Selecting only last part of the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following data [image]

I want the outcome to be like this:

[image]

For Albania, I want to select minimum and maximum values of date for the last value of City_Code (here, it's 20008) of Albania (The min value of date for 20008 is 18.01.2013, and max value for 20008 is 20.01.2013). For Croatia the last value of City_Code is 'zero', so we shouldn't select anything (if last value of 'City_Code' is zero, don't select it at all). For Slovenia, the last value of City_Code is 70005, so we select minimum and maximum values of corresponding dates (here maximum and minimum values are 22.01.2013). How should code look like? I don't have any idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
;
WITH    cte_countries ( Country, City_code, CurrentDate, LatestRank )
          AS ( SELECT   Country ,
                        City_code ,
                        CurrentDate ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY country ORDER BY CurrentDate DESC ) AS LatestRank
               FROM     @countries
               WHERE City_code != 0
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte_countries
    WHERE   LatestRank = 1
```

Comment: Most probably, it will work, but the program where I write code, does not accept with statement. Is there a way to write the same thing without with statement?))

Comment: This isn't actually 100% correct, I just noticed you wanted min date too...what version of SQL server have you got?

Comment: I don't know. It is actually some kind of program with implemeted sql server with real database.

Comment: can you run `SELECT @@VERSION`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Country,
       max(City_code),
       min(DATE),
       max(Date)
FROM T as T1
WHERE City_code = (SELECT TOP 1 City_Code 
                          FROM T WHERE T.Country=T1.Country 
                          ORDER BY Date DESC)
GROUP BY Country
HAVING max(City_Code)<>'0'
```

Comment: @SherzodMuminov According WHERE condition the `City_code` value is only ONE for each Country so you can use ANY grouping function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With Cities
AS (
    select Country, City_Code, Min([Date]) Date1, Max([Date]) Date2, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country, City_Code DESC) Seq
    from MyCountryCityTable t
    group by t.Country, t.City_Code
)
Select
    Country,
    NULLIF(City_Code,0) City_Code,
    CASE WHEN City_Code = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Date1 END Date1,
    CASE WHEN City_Code = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Date2 END Date2
From Cities Where Seq = 1
Order by Country
```

**EDIT:**

Version without the common table expression (`WITH`):

```
Select
    Country,
    NULLIF(City_Code,0) City_Code,
    CASE WHEN City_Code = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Date1 END Date1,
    CASE WHEN City_Code = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Date2 END Date2
From (select Country, City_Code, Min([Date]) Date1, Max([Date]) Date2, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country, City_Code DESC) Seq
    from MyCountryCityTable t
    group by t.Country, t.City_Code) Cities 
Where Seq = 1
Order by Country
```

Comment: Most probably, it will work, but the program where I write code, does not accept with statement. Is there a way to write the same thing without with statement?))